# Ruby global variable double dollar sign

Tags: ruby

I discovered a special global variable in Ruby. It's `$$` and it's always a number. But what does it mean? Even in the documentation I can't find anything.

Comment: It's a preset variable that represents the current process' ID.

Answer (score 4):

It's a preset variable that represents the current process' ID. It's documented in http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html.

`Process.pid` is an alternate, or use:

```
require 'English'
my_pid = $PROCESS_ID
```

In general, the short-cut globals are discouraged from use because they're like magical incantations or visual noise unless you know what they are.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the [pre-defined Ruby global variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/globals_rdoc.html).

All globals are prefixed with `$`, and in this case `$$` represents the current process ID. This was inherited from Perl.

Some things aren't very easy to search for, and `$$` is one of them, so it's understandable why you couldn't find it easily.

Comment: Good ol' Perl, the land of terse expressions and visual noise. :-)

Comment: @theTinMan Back from the days where code looked like line noise and we liked it.

Comment: `$$` is not a true variable though. At least you can't assign values to it.

Comment: @Aetherus It's considered a *read-only* variable. Just because you can't alter the value doesn't mean it's no longer a variable. A "constant" in Ruby is implemented differently.